# .exe files being opened in Microsoft Word instead of launched

Tags: windows, file-association

All `.exe` files on my computer are suddenly linked with Microsoft Word.

When I open an `.exe` file, Word launches and opens it instead of it being launched.

How do I restore the proper association for `.exe` files?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read [how to ask a good question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, it is set in the same place on all Windows versions. Go to Control Panel, and find "Programs" or "Default Programs" (depending on version of Windows). Then in the dialog that opens, you should see something like "Set file associations" or "Set default programs for files". Find an entry called ".exe" or "Executable" or "Windows Application", or whichever the name is on your version.

Delete the Word association and then it should work again.

Really strange though. To me, the issue smells like a virus that tries to execute code through a Word security hole.